# How to list only the instance id and related tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I using the CLI tools and I want to list only the instance ID and related tags of an instance. The command that I am using is ec2-describe instances. I have tried certain filters but nothing is working out.

Can anybody help ??

**error :**

```
./Instance_Audit.sh: line 24: $: command not found
./Instance_Audit.sh: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./Instance_Audit.sh: line 25: ` do echo $ID ; echo $(aws ec2 describe-instances  --query "Reservations[].Instances[?InstanceId==\`$ID\`].Tags[]") done'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the aws cli, I can produce a few different alternatives of the tag output:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Tags[]]'
Result: i-xxxxx [{u'Value': 'key1value', u'Key': 'key1name'}, {u'Value': 'key2value', u'Key': 'key2name'}]

aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Tags[].*]'
Result: i-xxxxx [['key1value', 'key1name'], ['key2value', 'key2name']]

aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Tags[].Key,Tags[].Value]'
Result: i-xxxx ['key1name', 'key2name'] ['key1value' 'key2value']
```

Is any of those formats what you're looking for?

Comment: Commands doesn't work, e.g. 1st one returns: `Bad value for --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId,Tags[]]: Unexpected token: ,: Parse error at column 39, token "," (COMMA), for expression:
"Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId,Tags[]]"`.

Answer (score 4):

The AWS CLI command

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,Tags[]]' --output text
```

produces these results:

```
i-789c55c3
Name    Instance1
aws:cloudformation:logical-id   Instance1
aws:cloudformation:stack-id     arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:012345678901:stack/test10-test10-foobarfoobar/a6e545a0-af52-11e4-a0be-50d5020578e0
aws:cloudformation:stack-name   test10-test10-foobarfoobar
i-77c108cc
Name    Instance2
aws:cloudformation:logical-id   Instance2
aws:cloudformation:stack-id     arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:012345678901:stack/test10-test10-foobarfoobar/a6e545a0-af52-11e4-a0be-50d5020578e0
aws:cloudformation:stack-name   test10-test10-foobarfoobar
```

If that is not in the format you are looking for, can you provide an example of they format you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only display the instance id and the tags associated to that instance, you can use something like :

`` $ for ID in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1 --query "Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId" --output text); do echo $ID ; echo $(aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1 --query "Reservations[].Instances[?InstanceId==\`$ID\`].Tags[]") done ``

`i-60****2a
[ [ { "Value": "SB", "Key": "Name" } ] ]
i-1a****56
[ [ { "Value": "Course and Schedule on Apache 2.4", "Key": "Name" } ] ]
i-88eff3cb
[ [ { "Value": "secret.com", "Key": "Name" } ] ]
i-e7****a5
[ [ { "Value": "2014.03 + Docker", "Key": "Name" } ] ]`

I could not find a way to do that with only one AWS CLI call.  Should someone come up with a shorter solution, I would love to hear from you.

If you want to filter to certain tag key/value only, you can edit the `aws ec2 describe-instances` to add a `--filter` option.

For example :

`aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1 --filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=SB"`

--Seb

Comment: `ec2-describe-instances|awk '/(Name|Owner)/&&/TAG/{if (!($3 in c)) {c[$3];b[++i]=$3;} a[$3,$4]=$5 OFS $6} END {for(k=1; k<=i; k++) print "TAG instance", b[i], "Name", a[b[i],"Name"], "Owner", a[b[i],"Owner"]}'` this is one command but its not working as appropriate

Comment: Please use the new command line and not the old one.  You can download AWS CLI from http://aws.amazon.com/cli/  This tool is installed on Amazon Linux distributions by default

Comment: i have configured that now how to proceed further

Comment: The AWS CLI documentation explains how to install and how to configure it : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html

Comment: that i have done. the output is in json format. now ho to fetch the instance id and tags like name, cost centre, owner from the json output in a file for 100 instances

Comment: See my original answer, it does it ! Change the region parameter to adapt it to your region

Comment: Either because you are not typing it correctly either because AWS CLI is not correctly configured.  It is very difficult to help without having the exact error message you're experiencing.  Also, before typing the command, decompose it in small parts and test the parts individually, just like you would do when writing code.  This will help you to narrow down the error

Comment: The initial $ is not part of the command.  It is the Linux shell prompt.  Have a look at http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html. This is not a AWS CLI problem, just a Linux shell script issue.  I will be glad to help you on any further problem you might have with AWS CLI itself

Comment: please see the current output and the expected output

Comment: you can add --output text in the second aws command (just like in the first one)  This would output the result as text instead of JSON

Comment: sir i want the output in the required format but i dnt know how to do this

Comment: sir now see the question , the out put is not in the formatted way also there are multiple tags that are not even required

Comment: You can use the --filter option to restrict the output to only tags you want.  I will edit the answer to show an example

Answer (score 0):

simple answer:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Tags[*]]'
```

not so simple answer .. the same principle could be applied to both instances and vpc's

```
# how-to get all the tags per instance-id with aws ec2 for prd env
while read -r i ; do \
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$i" \
--profile prd; done < <(aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId' --profile prd)

# how-to get all the tags per virtual-private-cloud-id 
while read -r v; do aws ec2 describe-tags \
--filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$v" ; \
done < <(aws ec2 describe-vpcs \
--query 'Vpcs[*].VpcId'|perl -ne 's/\t/\n/g;print')
```